# cakephp 2.1 and creating pdf

Tags: cakephp, pdf

hi all I'm trying to create an invoicing system however when i goto the related url i get a blank page and header just being the url. I've followed the following tutorial `[http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/kalileo/2010/06/08/creating-pdf-files-with-cakephp-and-tcpdf]`

here is my viewPdf function in the invoices controller

```
    function viewPdf($id = null) 
    { 
        if (!$id) 
        { 
            $this->Session->setFlash('Sorry, there was no property ID submitted.'); 
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index_admin'), null, true); 
        } 
        Configure::write('debug',0); // Otherwise we cannot use this method while developing 

        $id = intval($id); 

        $property = $this->__view($id); // here the data is pulled from the database and set for the view 

        if (empty($property)) 
        { 
            $this->Session->setFlash('Sorry, there is no property with the submitted ID.'); 
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'), null, true); 
        } 

        $this->layout = 'pdf'; //this will use the pdf.ctp layout 
        $this->render(); 
    } 

//End of Controller
}
```

and here is my viewPdf view

```
<?php 
App::import('Vendor','xtcpdf');  
$tcpdf = new XTCPDF(); 
$textfont = 'freesans'; // looks better, finer, and more condensed than 'dejavusans' 
$fpdf->xheadertext = 'YOUR ORGANIZATION';
$tcpdf->SetAuthor("KBS Homes & Properties at http://kbs-properties.com"); 
$tcpdf->SetAutoPageBreak( false ); 
$tcpdf->setHeaderFont(array($textfont,'',40)); 
$tcpdf->xheadercolor = array(150,0,0); 
$tcpdf->xheadertext = 'KBS Homes & Properties'; 
$tcpdf->xfootertext = 'Copyright Â© %d KBS Homes & Properties. All rights reserved.'; 

// add a page (required with recent versions of tcpdf) 
$tcpdf->AddPage(); 

// Now you position and print your page content 
// example:  
$tcpdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0); 
$tcpdf->SetFont($textfont,'B',20); 
$tcpdf->Cell(0,14, "Hello World", 0,1,'L'); 
// ... 
// etc. 
// see the TCPDF examples  

echo $tcpdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'D'); 

?>
```

to my knowledge it should be creating a pdf file that has the words 'hello world' written in it.

after following advice about that being outdated, I used the link to github and have this in my controller now

```
 public function view($id = null) {
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Invoices');
    $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
    $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.png');
    $this->layout='home_layout';
            $this->Invoice->id = $id;
            if (!$this->Invoice->exists()) {
                throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid invoice'));
            }
            $this->pdfConfig = array(
                'orientation' => 'potrait',
                'filename' => 'Invoice_' . $id
            );

            $this->set('invoice', $this->Invoice->read(null, $id));

        }
    }
```

and my view.ctp

```
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>
<body>
<?php $this->pdfConfig = array('engine' => 'CakePdf.WkHtmlToPdf') ?>
<?php echo $invoice; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

it prints out Array but does not render it as a pdf file

here is a link to the github pagw

https://github.com/ceeram/CakePdf

Answer (score 1):

Use this plugin, setup is on github page ;)

https://github.com/ceeram/CakePdf

Comment: im trying to install this and have questions on configuration, do you know who i should speak to or ask?

Answer (score 0):

this is an obsolete tutorial, this is a tutorial for Cakephp 1.2 and you are using 2.1.

It's much better the code from the link of GitHub that Matus Edko gave you.

By the way, is always better to show all the error and notifications when you are developing and testing, by setting up de "debug" to 3.

```
Configure::write('debug',3);
```

Comment: when using the one Matus printed, how does one write the views

Comment: Did you read https://github.com/ceeram/CakePdf#usage?? I am trying the first method from the examples but i am also getting a weird problem, nothing displays no pdf and no even an error. If i get something done i will let you know